# Get Email Address from Intent Filter in Android

Tags: android, intentfilter

How can I get email that comes through intent-filter in android ?
Currently I tried this, I could get the Action SEND, but the Extra_EMail is null.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    String type = intent.getType();


    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL);
    if (sharedText != null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sharedText,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        mEdit.setText(sharedText);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it should work only if you are passing recipient as array of string

try like this:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                      new String[] { "someone@gmail.com" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my helper function to send emails:

```
public static Intent email(Context context, String[] addresses, String subject, String body, Uri attachment) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822");
    if (addresses != null)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    if (body != null)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    if (subject != null)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (attachment != null)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    return intent;
}
```

You can use it this way inside an Activity:

```
startActivity(email(this, new String [] {"abc@def.com", "Subject of email", "Message inside email", null));
```