# get email address from intent filter

Tags: android, email, android-intent, intentfilter

Searched in stackoverflow, but could not find anything related, only this: [but answers are not related to OP question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25345293/get-email-address-from-intent-filter-in-android) So, I have this intent filter in my manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/>
            <data android:scheme="mailto"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
```

They are used for EMAIL and PHONE NUMBER intents. So everything works great, my application is being shown in list among others apps. What I would like to know is how to extract email and phone number from those intents?

Comment: Use `getIntent().getData()` to retrieve the `Uri` supplied to your activity. You will then need to poke through the `Uri` methods to see how best to pick out the email address and phone number from those `Uri` structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`Email` or phone number will be change to `uri`;

U can get them by reverse operating;

Comment: Try to debug and watch the Object.